# how to call hbase on a script

Tags: hbase, database, nosql

I want to call hbase on a script (basically a text file) that has certain commands like

```
disable 'block_data'
drop 'block_data'
create 'block_data', 'metadata', 'transactions'
describe 'block_data'
```

I want to know how to call this script from hbase or hbase shell to create a database table.

Answer (score 1):

```
#cat nameofscript | hbase shell
```